# How to run commands in the none-working directory in python?(not by giving the pathway)

Tags: python, directory, save

What I want to do is to make a sub-directory in the working-directory, and I want to run some of my commands in the sub-directory which in result the new files made will be saved in that directory. I have different types of file mainly `bam sam` and `txt`.
This is my command:

```
individual= raw_input("Please type the name of your individual")
os.mkdir(individual)
cmd="cd %s" %individual
os.mkdir("tst")
call(cmd, shell=True)
```

This is not working!In this example I tried to simply make another directory in the sub (to make it less complicated). I know that I can give the pathway! but since I have lot's of command I thought there might be an easier way!

Comment: The reason is that I want to run these commands several times with different data and I want to use the working directory for some of my common files and the sub for the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to create folders recursively:

```
folder = r'folders/to/create'
os.makedirs(folder)
os.chdir(folder)
# Your file saving code here
```

Alternatively, you could just construct the full filename, and use that when saving:

```
folder = r'folders/to/create'
os.makedirs(folder)
full_filename = os.path.join(folder, filename)
# Your file saving code here
```